# Is there any other way to use regular expressions in Java without using Pattern and Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

I'm researching about regular expressions. I wonder is there any other way to use this in Java without using Matcher and Pattern? I already google it but I can't find the answer.

Comment: its depends on what you want to do with the regex!

Comment: In details, I wonder if there are other way use regex with better performance than Matcher and Pattern, which is the best way to use regex. btw, I use regex to find substring that match the regex.

Comment: in that case, yes. you can manipulate the `String#replaceAll()` function with regex

Comment: replaceAll() fuction is also implemented with Pattern, isn't it?

Comment: Ahh! never aware of it :D

Answer (score 0):

If there is a alternative that can provide full functionality of Pattern and Matcher, then why we need duplicated APIs then?

Depending on what you need to do, Java did provide some convenient APIs in String class for some simple and common action, for example:

```
String.matches(regex);
String.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
String.replaceFirst(regex, replacement);
String.split(regex);
```

Comment: By the way, `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` is also implemented with Pattern in Oracle implementation. (Well, generally, it is slower, but it is faster than naive implementation in worst case)

Comment: @nhahtdh interesting finding :) although it does not relate to what OP asked, it is still fun to know :)

Comment: I didn't looking for a alternative that can provide full functionality of Pattern and Matcher. :) I just wonder if there is any other way to use regex might have better performance. Anyway, thank for your answer :)

Comment: What are you looking for in fact? What makes you unsatisfied with Pattern and Matcher?  Be precise in your question please.  Unless you are using external libraries, Pattern/Matcher which is the only Java regex library is the only way and the best you can have with Java.

Comment: I didn't mean that I unsatisfied with Pattern and Matcher. What I really want is to find any other ways (including external libraries) to compare their performance with Pattern/Matcher.

Comment: Then be clear in your question.  And, such kind of question is considered as inappropriate in StackOverflow because 1. it ask for library suggestion, 2. it is subjective.

Comment: I don't believe if you have Googled, you cannot find other regex library for Java.  Simply search for "java regex library" already give me several alternative libraries in first page

Answer (score 0):

Java SE 7 and later includes a [built-in Javascript interpreter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) which you can call. Javascript includes [built-in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You could use the Javascript RE engine instead of the Java functions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class RESample {
    private final static String script =
            "var pattern = /;/;\n" +
            "var names = input;\n" +
            "var nameList = names.split(pattern);\n" +
            "nameList.forEach(function(name) { output.add(name);});";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        String input = "Tom;Dick;Harry";
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        engine.put("input", input);
        engine.put("output", output);
        engine.eval(script);
        for (String name : output) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thank for your answer. What about its performance? It's seem like more complex than Pattern and Matcher :) By the way, I'm not good with Javascript.

Comment: @jenny Beats me. You didn't ask about better ways to do regular expressions, just "other" ways.